# Server Sent Events and GET request on same route - best practise?

Tags: http, content-type, server-sent-events

I want to be able to either "long poll", via the usage of Server Sent Events, to an endpoint that returns a stream of a particular time dependent value as well as perform an ordinary GET request that returns the current time value.

I was wondering, firstly, should this be something that is allowed?

Secondly, should I differentiate what is returns by using the `ContentType` header, returning dependent on whether the request wants `ContentType: text/event-stream` or, for example, any other `ContentType` returns the "moment in time" (non-streamed response) return?

Update: I'm just going to route base on Accept headers.